# Better way to do a replacement to define a function

Tags: replacement, symbolic, syntax

I have a long analytical process where I have defined a stand in function `Int[]` to act as a placeholder for either `NIntegrate[]` or `Integrate[]`. This way I can do algebra on equations that involve integrals without having *Mathematica* try to actually do the integration.  However, at the end when I place in some numbers and leave some parameters to be defied later I always get a warning messages. Below is a very simple example that demos the issue:

After the analytical work say I'm left with:

```
fun = 42 Int[Exp[-(x/a)^2] + b, {x, 0, 5}]
```

I now want to create a function with the parameters `a` and `b`

```
NewFun[a_, b_] := Evaluate[fun /. {Int -> NIntegrate}]
```

I get the warning: NIntegrate::inumr

Is there a better way to replace `Int` with `NIntegrate` then define my function?
I realize I could just turn off the message but that feels like cheating.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to pass numeric-parameters `a,b` to function `fun`!

Try

```
fun[a_?NumericQ, b_?NumericQ] := 42 Int[Exp[-(x/a)^2] + b, {x, 0, 5}]
NewFun[a_, b_] := fun[a, b] /. {Int -> NIntegrate}
NewFun[1,1]
(*247.222*)
```

Comment: In my process I have to start with `fun=stuff` but I can do `funaux[a_?NumericQ,b_?NumericQ]:=Evaluate[fun];` then use `funaux`. But when I look at your `?NewFun` it still has the replacement to do once called. Is there not a way to get the replacement done in the definition of `NewFun` ?

Answer (score 0):

[`Inactivate`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Inactivate.html) and [`Activate`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Activate.html)

```
f[a_, b_] := Inactivate[Integrate[a x + b, {x, 0, 5}], Integrate]
f[3, 4] // Activate
```